# how to run jersey server from the jar (eclipse)

Tags: java, jersey

I used jersey to develop a small server doing

```
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
server.start();
```

and a small api like this:

```
@GET
@Path("serverconnectiontest")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CommunicationResponseM isDatabaseOnline()
{
    CommunicationResponseM result = new CommunicationResponseM();


    return result;
}
```

in eclipse if I start the server with right_click->run as->java application all go well, so if I type the path in my web browser I can see the server response..

now I want to make a jar of my server, so I do:
right_click->export->runanble_jar  and I get the jar file.. but if I ran this jar using "java -jar file.jat" the server doesn't respond and give me this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class
it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and Java type class 
it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and MIME media type
application/json was not found

Mar 14, 2013 6:59:10 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write

SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json -> 
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App

com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

Mar 14, 2013 6:59:10 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body     
writer for Java class it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and Java type   
class it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and MIME media type   
application/json was not found
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
at    

   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.httpserver.HttpHandlerContainer.handle(HttpHandlerContainer.java:191)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:557)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:529)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
 Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class    
it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and Java type class     
it.unitn.se.gym.backend.models.CommunicationResponseM, and MIME media type   
application/json was not found
```

can you help me?

thnaks  a lot!

if I try to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured a MANIFEST.MF file pointing to the Main class to run? More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: no, becouse i'm usign a normal java project, there is no MANIFEST:MF file

Comment: If you want an executable jar, you need a MANIFEST.MF file. So either you have to get Eclipse to generate one for you, or create one by hand.

Comment: I unpacked the .jar file and I noted that there is a .mf file

it contains "Rsrc-Main-Class: it.unitn.se.gym.backend.WebService", webservice is the class where the server starts… there is also "Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"

Comment: Also, add some log statements to your code so you can trace what is happening during startup and execution. It'll be easier to track down the error with some more information.

Comment: I update the open post with the error that the console give me when I try to contact the server

Comment: If it works within Eclipse but not standalone I would guess it is a classpath issue (some missing jar files). I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but make sure that all the required dependencies are exported in the executable jar as well.